# How to de-populate a Kivy Treeview?

Tags: python-2.7, treeview, kivy

Given the Treeview example in the kivy doc, I am looking for a way to de-populate a Treeview. But I can't find (am unable to design) a clear and concise solution that will also work for treeviews with nesting levels more than 3 (my trials consist of unmaintainable if-elif etc. decision trees).

So a de-populate of the following example should convert the Treeview into a new tree dictionary with the result that the new tree dictionary is exactly the same as tree in the example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel, TreeView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


tree = {'node_id': '1',
        'children': [{'node_id': '1.1',
                      'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1',
                                    'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1.1',
                                                  'children': []}]},
                                   {'node_id': '1.1.2',
                                    'children': []},
                                   {'node_id': '1.1.3',
                                    'children': []}]},
                      {'node_id': '1.2',
                       'children': []}]}
# EDIT
def treeToDict(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeView):
        node = node.root
    if node.text == 'Tree One':
        node = node.nodes[0]
    d = dict()
    d['node_id'] = node.text
    d['children'] = []
    for child in node.nodes:
        d['children'].append(treeToDict(child))
    return d
# EDIT END

class TreeWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Tree One'),
                      hide_root=False,
                      indent_level=4)

        populate_tree_view(tv, None, tree)

        self.add_widget(tv)

        # EDIT
        print treeToDict(tv)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TreeWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**EDIT**:

With depopulate I don't mean removing nodes but converting the treeview in a dictionary. The reason why is as follows.
I have a content-editor building building up a treeview of objects. This object structure needs to be stored in a database in such a way that it is easy to reproduce in the editor again using the populate_tree_view function.

Thanks very much in advance for sharing your knowledge, time and efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why the depopulated tree should be the same, but here is a simple depopulate method:

```
def depopulate(tv):
    iterator = tv.iterate_all_nodes()
    try:
        while True:
            node = iterator.next()
            tv.remove_node(node)
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

This should remove all the nodes in the tree, leaving just the root.

To create a dictionary of the nodes, the following method should work:

```
def treeToDict(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeView):
        node = node.root
    if node.text == 'Tree One':
        node = node.nodes[0]
    d = dict()
    d['node_id'] = node.text
    d['children'] = []
    for child in node.nodes:
        d['children'].append(treeToDict(child))
    return d
```

The initial `if` statements in this method are just to skip over the `TreeView` widget and the root widget ('Tree One'). If you can be sure to call this method with the top level node (`node_id` == `1`), then you can remove those `if` statements. The method returns the dict.

Comment: Dear John, thanks for your reply. With depopulate I don't mean removing nodes but converting the treeview into a dictionary. See EDIT.

Comment: @BillBridge, I have added another method to my answer that should do what you want.

Comment: Dear John, thanks for your update and great solution. However, it is still missing a level of children. When running the method it produces the following result: {'node_id': '1', 'children': [{'node_id': '1.1', 'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1', 'children': []}]}]}.

Comment: As soon as child['children'] is an empty list the conversion does not add the node dict to d. Unfortunately I am struggling to get this right. Please could you have a further look at it?

Comment: Odd. When I pass the `TreeView` object that is createtd in the `__init__()` method of `TreeWidget`, here is the dict that it creates: `dict = {'node_id': '1', 'children': [{'node_id': '1.1', 'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1', 'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1.1', 'children': []}]}, {'node_id': '1.1.2', 'children': []}, {'node_id': '1.1.3', 'children': []}]}, {'node_id': '1.2', 'children': []}]}`. Did you copy the method exactly? The `return d` statement should not be indented.

Comment: Hi John, you are right. Thanks. A minor edit mistake. Sorry. The method works perfectly. Thanks very much and happy Eastern holidays.